# React native TextInput box-shadow

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I want to apply a shadow on TextInput, as shown here:
[image]

I am making this style, using shadow, and elevation for android:

```
shadowColor: colors.shadowColor,
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 3,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 0,
      width: 0,
    },
    elevation: 2,
```

However, the result is not as expected. So, I am asking if there's a way to enhance it without passing by a 3rd party package.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the [react-native-cardview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cardview) package, results are much better, however, it is so limited, that I can't set the shadow color and other options.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  ScrollView,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import CardView from 'react-native-cardview';
import styles from './styles';

export default class Signup extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.whiteColor }}>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.signupContainer}>
            <View style={styles.signupInputs}>
              <CardView
                style={styles.cardStyle}
                cardElevation={2}
                cardMaxElevation={2}
                cornerRadius={5}
              >
                <TextInput
                  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                  style={[styles.signupInput, styles.commonsignupStyle]}
                  placeholder="Nom *"
                  placeholderTextColor={colors.primaryColor}
                />
              </CardView>
              <CardView
                style={styles.cardStyle}
                cardElevation={2}
                cardMaxElevation={2}
                cornerRadius={5}
              >
                <TextInput
                  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                  style={[styles.signupInput, styles.commonsignupStyle]}
                  placeholder="Prénom *"
                  placeholderTextColor={colors.primaryColor}
                />
              </CardView>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]